# Changing a code to get the Goldbach conjecture

Tags: matlab

To test the Golbach conjecture I have found the following code, but when I ren it out, this only gives me the number of combinations of primes, but in fact what I was searching for are the primes,I mean the couple of primes such that I get the even number.
Can someone help me to change the below code in matlab to get the couple of primes?

```
function y=goldbach_partition(n)
if mod(n,2)==0
    y=0;
    for i=2:floor(n/2)
        if isprime(i) & isprime(n-i)
            y=y+1;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple.  Create a new array that will store the prime number `i` (or `n-i`... can't say for sure) in an array should the value `i` (and `n-i`) pass the criterion, then return that array.  BTW, you should move your `y=0` statement outside of the `if` statement, because if `n` is odd, you will never see `y` being output and you'll get an error.

Something like this:

```
function [y,pmes]=goldbach_partition(n) %// Change
y = 0; %// Change
pmes = []; %// Change
if mod(n,2)==0
    for i=2:floor(n/2)
        if isprime(i) & isprime(n-i)
            y=y+1;
            pmes = [pmes; i n-i]; %// Change
        end
    end
end
```

I'm not sure which prime number you're after - if it's `i` or `n-i`, so I've added them both.  I've also made sure that both primes should they meet the condition be placed in a single row of your matrix.  This way, each row will give you when a pair of primes has passed the condition.

Therefore, the above code will not only return the total number of primes, it'll return an array of all of the primes that passed the condition.

You would then call your function this way in MATLAB:

```
[y,pmes] = goldbach_partition(n);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :), let me check it out, give a minute please :)

Comment: @user162343 - No worries.  Make sure you check my edits.  I don't know which prime you're after.. .`i` or `n-i`, so I've added them both.  Let me know which one you're after and I'll modify the code.

Comment: I am back :), the thing is that I dont understand how to call this function out, for a first computing I wrote [y,pmes]=goldbach_partition1(26),I wrote the number 1 because I am running your code and the one I posted :)

Comment: You need to change the first line of the code so that it's `function [y,pmes] = goldbach_partition1(n)`.  The name of the file **has to be the same as the function name**.  That is basic MATLAB syntax.

Comment: jjajaja I am sorry ;), that is right, one more thing, how do I display the primes in a 2d array?

Comment: @user162343 - Ah.  That's easy.  One moment.

Comment: @user162343 - Done.  Check the edit.  It only needed a small modification to one line of code... namely, the `;` character.

Comment: Right :), and one more thing, can you helpme with one more code, I will post it in a different question so it will be easy to veify :)

Comment: So just give some minutes to post my question and I comment here the link :),Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, one more thing here, I want to plot the number of primes, versus the even number, I have tried unsing n=[2:2:6] and then plot (goldbach_partition(n),n) but matlab says that more input is needed, what can I do ?

Comment: Give some minutes to check this out and , post my other quiestion right?

Comment: I am sorry for the delay, but the code you have gave me for the plot, doesn't plot, it just give me a blanck space :(

Comment: @user162343 - Probably because you chose bad values of `n`.  Make the vector bigger.  I get an output.

Comment: Well I have type down the code I posted, the code you toldme, and matlab tells me that goldbach_partition needs more imput, then I wrote goldbach_partition(26) (With the code that you wrote :)) and theres is only blanck space :(

Comment: `figure; hold on; for n = 2 : 2 : 6, y = goldbach_partition(n); plot(n, y, 'b.');`

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88394/discussion-between-rayryeng-and-user162343